# Changing state value in parent does not cause rerender of child component that uses the state value

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I have 2 lists - each a separate component (list1,list2). List1 lists quick info items that each by index correspond to the same indexed item in list2 which shows further details to the item.

Initially each list shows 12 items and 12 further items can be "opened" by clicking a button thats underneath each list. The functions (doShowMoreX, doShowMoreY) that get triggered when each button is pressed live in the parent component and are passed down to the list-child-components where they are used to determine the list's height with inline jsx.css. This works fine.

Pressing the button inside list1-component opens the list of list1 and pressing the button inside list2 opens list 2. However, list1 shall also be able to open list 2 and that is when list 2 does not open/rerender (scrollToDetails() inside parent component below).

**Parent component:**

```
export const parent = ({ hours, day, location, context, utcDate }) => {

const numItemsToShow:number = 12;
const [showMoreX, setShowMoreX] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [showMoreY, setShowMoreY] = useState<boolean>(false);

const doShowMoreX = (e): void => {
    setShowMoreX(!showMoreX); //rerendering of list1 works
}

const doShowMoreY = (e): void => {
    if (!showMoreY) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMoreY(true); //rerendering of list2 works
    }
}

const scrollToDetails = (e) => {
        console.log('please open detailed list') //is being consoled 
        setShowMoreY(true); //PROBLEM: does not rerender/open list Y
}

return (
    <>
        <ErrorBoundary>
            {
                (context === 'detailed') ?
                    <VhsHourDetailed day={day} hours={hours} state={{ showMoreY, setShowMoreY, showMoreAmountY }} location={location} toggleShowMore={doShowMoreY} utcDate={utcDate} /> :
                    <VhsHourShort day={day} hours={hours} state={{ showMoreX, showMoreAmountX, showMoreAmountTotalX }} location={location} toggleShowMore={doShowMoreX} scrollToDetails={scrollToDetails} utcDate={utcDate} />
            }
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </>
)
}
```

**list 1:**

```
export const list1 = ({ hours, day, state, location, utcDate, toggleShowMore, scrollToDetails }) => {
const {showMoreX} = state;
    <OuterCnt>
        <Cnt style={{ width: `${(showMoreX) ? showMoreAmountTotalX + 'px' : showMoreAmountX + 'px'}` }}>
            <HoursCntShort id="hours_cnt_short" className="hours_cnt_short">
                {
                    hours.length &&
                    hours.map((hour: VhsHourTypes, idx) => {
                        const hourNum = hour.date.getHours();
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={idx}>
                                <HourCntShort onClick={scrollToDetails} data-idx={`idx_${idx}`} className="hour_cnt_short show_more_item">
                                 </HourCntShort>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </HoursCntShort>
        </Cnt>
    </OuterCnt>
)
```

}

**list 2**

```
export const list2 = ({ day, hours, state, location, utcDate, toggleShowMore }) => {

const { showMoreY, showMoreAmountY } = state;

return (
        <List>.....</List>
        <ShowMoreBtn href={`/wetter_aktuell/wettervorhersage/morgen/${location.slug}`} onClick={toggleShowMore}>
            <span>{`${(showMoreY) ? 'Wetter Morgen' : 'weitere Stunden'}`}</span>
            <IconSpan><IconDropDown /></IconSpan>
        </ShowMoreBtn>
)
```

}

Comment: try to debug the function `doShowMoreY` and remove the if statement and update us

Comment: doShowMoreY works fine (pressing list2 button opens list2 but pressing an item in list1 does not open list2). It is the scrollToDetails-function that is in charge for the latter